# Conserved quantity for my constant coefficients 2D ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\begin{pmatrix}x’\\y’\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}$ has zero trace. I am having trouble making a conserved quantity $C(x,y)$ such that I can observe the shape of $z=C(x,y)$.
Follow ups: can we construct a conserved quantity if trace is not zero? I have strong evidence it is not possible based on fundamentals, but how would I prove this if so.
Grateful for any help.

Comment: what does it mean to say $X'=MX$ has zero trace, do you mean $M$ has zero trace?

Comment: Dear Calvin this was one of my concerns too. I believe M has zero trace is what it is announcing. What could we deduce about the eigenvalues in that case?

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

As the coefficients are constant, the derivatives curve $(x',y')$ also is a solution. The Wronskian determinant is then a constant along solutions, as per $\frac{d}{dt}\det(e^{tM})=\,{\rm tr}(M)\det(e^{tM})$.
$$
\det\pmatrix{x&x'\\y&y'}=\det\pmatrix{x&ax+by\\y&cx-ay}=cx^2-2axy-by^2=C(x,y).
$$

Test that the derivative of this is indeed zero:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(cx^2-2axy-by^2)
=2((cx-ay)\dot x-(ax+by)\dot y)
\\
=2((cx-ay)(ax+by)-(ax+by)(cx-ay))=0
$$

Comment: Is it possible for this process to occur if trace is not zero?

Comment: In principle yes, only that you then get $C(x(t),y(t))=e^{{\rm tr}(M)t}C(x(0),y(0))$, and in general you will also not find another constant of motion.